# How to write a crontab entry on a cPanel host?

Tags: php, cron

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/liquidst/common/ads-management/admin/scrpnews.php
```

I want to write cronjob in my cPanel. I want this page loads after every 5 minutes. Is there any problem in my command?

Comment: If you want to get your actual code reviewed, post it on the correct site: [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In and of itself, this isn't _"wrong"_ for a crontab entry, but be careful: php can be configured differently for CLI and apache/nginx (check /etc/php5/ subdirectories for different conf.d's)

Comment: Are you actually editing a crontab via your console? Or are you adding this entry via cPanel? Crontab config files will have the time config at the start e.g. `*/5 * * * *`.

Comment: i am adding this via cPanel and yes i also cofig the start

Comment: i got email from cron daemon 
Could not open input file: /home/liquidst/common/ads-management/admin/scrpnews.php